# import_playbook pass variable but it doesn't work in when condition

Tags: ansible

I've main yml (`select.yml`) which reuse `machine-id.yml`.

Both has prompt to ask for host ip, so I can run `machine-id.yml` directly and it will ask for IP.

`select.yml` as main script has also prompt for asking IP. But because it reuse `machine-id.yml`, I don't want to ask twice for IP, because in future I will add another subscript with another prompt maybe.

Problem I faced is that `machine-id.yml` takes `dynamic_hosts` value from `select.yml`. And it works - I can run `select.yml` and it will ask me for IP twice. When I put IP1 as prompt value and IP2 as second one, I see tasks are run on both hosts.

but I cannot use `when:` to prevent prompt in `machine-id.yml`. It says variable is not defined in debug. Also did not react on condition `dynamic_hosts is not defined`

select.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
  - name: target_host
    prompt: "[M] please enter the target host IP"
    private: no
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ target_host }}"
        groups: dynamic_hosts
        
- import_playbook: machine_id.yml
```

machine-id.yml:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
       var: dynamic_hosts
    - name: PROMPT
      block:      
        - name: ask host
          pause:
            prompt: "Please enter target IP"        
          register: target_host          
        - name: add to dynamic_hosts
          add_host:
            name: "{{ target_host.user_input }}"
            groups: dynamic_hosts2        
      when: dynamic_hosts is not defined       

- hosts: dynamic_hosts
  vars:  
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Reset machine-id
      shell: rm /etc/machine-id && rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id && dbus-uuidgen --ensure=/etc/machine-id && dbus-uuidgen --ensure
      args:
        warn: no
```

Comment: I believe your `when:` in `machine_id.yml` should be `target_host is not defined` or else `when: '"dynamic_hosts" not in groups'` because (AFAIK) `dynamic_hosts` is not a var, but is instead a key in `groups`

Comment: `vars_prompt` are not shared between plays. There are some workarounds for that. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444964/why-i-cannot-prompt-for-a-variable-that-will-be-shared-by-multiple-plays-ansibl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dynamic_hosts` is not a variable, it's an element in the list of `groups`. You can debug that if you do a `debug var=groups`

You have to access it via `groups.dynamic_hosts`.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
       var: groups.dynamic_hosts
    - name: PROMPT
      block:      
        - name: ask host
          pause:
            prompt: "Please enter target IP"        
          register: target_host          
        - name: add to dynamic_hosts
          add_host:
            name: "{{ target_host.user_input }}"
            groups: dynamic_hosts2        
      when: groups.dynamic_hosts is not defined
```