# Ansible: Issues with vars_prompt, error: variable is undefined

Tags: variables, ansible, host

I think I may be using vars_prompt incorrectly because when I define a variable (used as a host) from command line, the host is used for the following task correctly:

`ansible-playbook newfile -v -e 'target_host=uat:prd'`

```
- hosts '{{ target_host }}'
  tasks:
     ...
```

But when I define the same variable using vars_prompt:

```
- name: run task
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
  - name: target_host
    prompt: please choose a host site
    private: no

- hosts: '{{ target_host }}'
  tasks:
   ...
```

I get error: 'target_host' is undefined pointing at the - hosts: '{{ target_host }}'

Note: it does ask the prompt before getting the error

Thank you for the suggestion to add to host group @JBone. Sadly I have already tried this approach and I get:

`Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname uat:prd: Name or service not known`

Even though if I fill the host in the playbook as uat:prd it runs on each host

- this approach does work for uat or prd by themselves but not uat:prd

Comment: It's a variable scope issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444964/why-i-cannot-prompt-for-a-variable-that-will-be-shared-by-multiple-plays-ansibl for workarounds. Maybe `hosts: '{{ hostvars['localhost']['target_host'] }}'` could work.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this variable value to a new `host group` using `add_host` module.

```
- name: run task
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
  - name: target_host
    prompt: please choose a host site
    private: no
  tasks:
  - name: add host
    add_host:
      name: "{{ target_host }}"
      groups: new_hosts_grp


- hosts: new_hosts_grp
  tasks:
   ...
```

try that one.

Comment: Thank you @JBone but I'm afraid it does not work, see my edit

Comment: have you tried it? if so what error are you getting? why are you passing `target_host` from command line also prompting for the input for that variable?

Comment: yes I have tried it and put the error in the question ```Failed to connect```. No I do not pass ```target_host``` from command line when prompting, I just did it to demonstrate that passing works and prompting does not